# How to increment all fields named 'task.progress' with value less then other field named task.max in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How to increment value of all fields named 'task.progress' with value less then other field named 'task.max' in mongodb?

```
{
  "login": "xxx",
  "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
  "task": {
    "name": "",
    "max": NumberInt(200),
    "progress": NumberInt(0)
  }
}
```

I want to increment by 1 field 'task.progress' if its less then 'task.max':
In output I want to get:

```
{
  "login": "xxx",
  "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
  "task": {
    "name": "",
    "max": NumberInt(200),
    "progress": NumberInt(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Show input and output data example

Comment: Nobody knows? It seems like to be easy but i am new in mongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.your_col.updateMany(
    {task: {$exists: 1}, $where: 'this.task.progress < this.task.max'},
    {$inc: {'task.progress': 1}})
```

It's mongodb shell, mongodb 3.4

Comment: It doesn't work. I am afraid you cannot use $where to subfields. 
  
From mongodb documentation: 

"Only apply the $where query operator to top-level documents. The $where query operator will not work inside a nested document"

Comment: I don't know why.. Can someone else know?

Comment: if you can write correct query for your mongodb client, it will work.

Comment: In single query, you can't compare fields in document without where operator.

Comment: I found a solution. All documents must have a field 'task'. If at least one does not have it does not work.

Comment: You can include $exists operator in my query.

Comment: btw, upvote my query to show other users that it's useful answer